# Firebase Storage security rules: duration.value parameter

Tags: firebase, metadata, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I'm trying to secure my Firebase Storage files based on time access, let's say only allowing files to be read up to a specific time after they were uploaded.

This specific time is stored into a custom property 'expiration' field in the file metadata when it is uploaded by the user.

My problem is that I'm trying to use this value as a parameter into the `duration.value(int magnitude, string units)` function like so:

```
request.time < resource.timeCreated + duration.value(resource.metadata.expiration, "m");
```

But the 'duration' function only seems to accept constant values into the magnitude parameter and not dynamic values.

Anyone out there that has tried this too?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question, sorry you're having trouble :(

Yes, these functions do take dynamic values--the issue here is that the type is wrong, and thus the function is failing.

All custom metadata (as "expiration" is), is returned as a string, while `duration.value()` takes an `int` and a `string`, as you correctly pointed out.

The simple (though as of yet undocumented) way of doing this, is to cast the `string` value to an `int`, using the `int()` method:

```
request.time < resource.timeCreated + duration.value(int(resource.metadata.expiration), "m");
```

Comment: After investigating deeply I thought it could be due to wrong type but I didn't know that is possible to do castings. Nice!

Comment: Yep, it's all a docs issue unfortunately (I'm working to get them updated)